# Print all unique prime factors of a number in ascending order

Tags: java

I'm a beginner and completely confused!
I need to display all the prime divisors of a number, but in the first code the calculation takes long time, and in the second code, if I enter the number 2, then java prints 1 and 2, but I just need 2.

**Example:**

```
input 360
output 2 3 5

input 2
output 2

input 999999797
output 999999797
```

If I enter 999999797 then  "*time limit*"
what's my mistakes?

```
for (d = 2; x > 1; d++) {
    if (x % d == 0) {
        x = x / d;
        for (int i = 0; x % d == 0; i++) {
            x = x / d;
        }
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

AND

```
 for (d = 2; x % d == 0; d++) {
     for (int i = 0; x % d == 0; i++) {
        x = x / d;
     }
     System.out.println(d);
 }
 System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up the code for the first snippet (which actually is nice) would be:

```
    int d = 2;
    int step = 1;
    while (x > 1) {
        if (x % d == 0) {
            System.out.println(d);
            x /= d;
            while (x % d == 0) {
                x /= d;
            }
        }
        d += step;
        step = 2;
    }
```

I added a small optimisation to test only 2, 3, 5, 7, 9 and so on,
to demonstrate that many divisors are not needed to be tested. Half the candidates.

Generalized to skip 2, 3, 5:

For a number modulo 2 * 3 * 5:

```
// Unneeded code:
boolean[] dividable = new int[2*3*5]; // non-candidates to be skipped.
for (int i = 0; i < dividable.length; ++i) {
    dividable[i] = i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0;
}
// cycle length: 2*3*5 == 30.
// result: tfttt ttftt tftft ttftf tttft ttttf
// steps:   2      7   11 13  17 19  23     29 (8 from 30 candidates, a fourth)
```

Then the code could be optimized (more ugly though) further:

```
final int cycleLength = 2*3*5;
final int[] initialSteps = {  2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29};
final int[] nextSteps =    {1,         7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29};
int[] steps = initialSteps;
for (int b = 0; x > 1; b += cycleLength) {
    for (int i = 0; x > 1 && i < steps.length; ++i) {
        int d = b + steps[i];
        while (x > 1) {
            if (x % d == 0) {
                System.out.println(d);
                x /= d;
                while (x % d == 0) {
                    x /= d;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    steps = nextSteps;
}
```

Slightly less than five times faster. *(Untested code.)*

> For those with an interest in  math: notice how the `steps` are
> ofcourse primes themselves, and the condition for the `initialSteps`
> should contain `(i % P == 0 && i / P == 1)`.

---

***Without arrays, using bits instead***

As one of the requirements seems to be to avoid arrays (though here they are of fixed limited length), one can use bits. For 30 bits an int suffices.

```
final int cycleLength = 2*3*5;
final int common = 1<<7 | 1<<11 | 1<<13 | 1<<17
       | 1<<19 | 1<<23 | 1<<29;
final int initialSteps = 1<<2 | 1<<3 | 1<<5 | common;
final int nextSteps =   1<<1 | common;
long steps = initialSteps;
for (int b = 0; x > 1; b += cycleLength) {
    for (int i = 0, int mask = 1; x > 1 && i < cycleLength; ++i, mask <<= 1) {
        if ((steps & mask) != 0) {
            int d = b + i;
            while (x > 1) {
                if (x % d == 0) {
                    System.out.println(d);
                    x /= d;
                    while (x % d == 0) {
                        x /= d;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    steps = nextSteps;
}
```

Be warned that this is even more ugly, and I am far from sure the code is correct.

Comment: Oh thanks!!! I'm going to analyse over this solution!
I need a nested for loop in my task without using arrays. Can this be done more gracefully than my code above?

Comment: I use only limited array in the second code snippet. The first code snippet improves only by a factor 2

Comment: I added a non-array version, using bits and bit operations. `BitSet`  would have been possible too. The logic is that in in numbers modulo 2*3*5 the multiples of 2, 3, and 5 are at fixed positions. Explain that as comment.

Comment: damn, my brain is too dumb for this..
thanks this is useful!!